# Can I compile Java source (which uses Swing and other libraries) into exe so that it does not need JavaSE?

Tags: java, compilation, exe, native

Is it posible to compile Java source (which uses libraries like Swing etc) in an exe file, so the user doesn't need to install JavaSE?

I am looking for some way to bundle a mini-JRE and the .jar in a single file (exe) or some way to compile everything (source and libraries) into native code.

PS: Obviously I don't care about cross-compat for that program.

Comment: You can exe your stuff but java code would always require JVM. The other option you mentioned looks probable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven